# DataGrid is not redrawing when ItemsSource property changes

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have a page in my Navigatable Silverlight Application similar to the following (proprietary references removed):

```
 <navigation:Page x:Class="MyNamespace.MachineView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
                 xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" 
                 xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" 
                 xmlns:common="-- proprietary reference --" 
                 xmlns:res="-- proprietary reference --"
                 xmlns:sclHelpers="-- proprietary reference --" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 d:DesignWidth="1024" d:DesignHeight="768"
                 res:Strings.Assignment="Title=MachineView.Title">
    <Border Margin="35,10,35,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <toolkit:HeaderedContentControl d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height, GridBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
                    <toolkit:HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                        <TextBlock res:Strings.Assignment="Text=MachineView.ReadyProjectsTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}"/>

                    </toolkit:HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <sdk:DataGrid Background="#7FFFFFFF" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ReadyProjects}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Margin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MinHeight="75">
                            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn res:Strings.Assignment="Header=MachineView.ProjectNumberLabel"
                                    Binding="{Binding ProjectNumberText, FallbackValue=[Project Number]}" 
                                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn res:Strings.Assignment="Header=MachineView.ProjectNameLabel"
                                    Binding="{Binding NameText, FallbackValue=[Project Name]}"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn res:Strings.Assignment="Header=MachineView.ProjectStatusLabel"
                                    Binding="{Binding StatusText, FallbackValue=[Status]}"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                        </sdk:DataGrid>
                        <common:MiniBusyControl Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,24,0,0" Visibility="{Binding ReadyProjects.IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock res:Strings.Assignment="Text=EmptyText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="{Binding ReadyProjects.ShowEmpty, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,24,0,0" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                    </Grid>
                </toolkit:HeaderedContentControl>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</navigation:Page>
```

The `DataGrid` is not redrawn when the collection that is bound to the `ItemSource` property is initially populated.  The collection is a type that inherits directly from `ObservableCollection<T>` in order to wrap other properties up with the collection (i.e. `IsBusy` and `ShowEmpty`).  Whenever I resort or resize a column of the `DataGrid` UI, the data shows up, so its most certainly a redraw problem. It is as if there is a bug within the control itself.  I am using an MVVM decoupled model, but I am very close to just hacking the code behind of this page to call Measure on the `DataGrid` directly.  I've tested the backend and it is working properly; sending the appropriate collection and property change notifications. This is indeed very frustrating.

**Edits**

I've discovered that if I instead use `ObservableCollection<T>` directly, it all works.  I'm thinking that the Silverlight `DataGrid` has some hard-coded dependency on the `ObservableCollection<T>` type.  Does anyone have any insight into this hypothesis?  Say it aint so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'm an idiot sometimes.  My problem was this: I overloaded `ObservableCollection<T>`'s `OnCollectionChanged` method but never actually called the base class's version of it.

*Sigh.*

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

A sample of your view model might help.  I'm guessing the observable collection in `ReadyProjects` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `IsBusy` and `ShowEmpty`.  Does your DataContext implement and fire property changed for the `ReadyProjects` property itself, to register the initial set?

Comment: The collections themselves use INotifyCollectionChanged.  I'm constructing the collection when I construct my view model.  I'm using MEF to glue together the view (Page) with its view model.  I'll try calling the PropertyChanged event manually when I update the collection.

Comment: Nope, its doing the same thing.

Comment: I've discovered that using ObservableCollection<T> works fine.  I am starting to think that the DataGrid only uses INotifyCollectionChanged when it is dealing with an ObservableCollection<T>.  That is it is checking for (typeof(itemSource) == typeof( ObservableCollection<T>)).  This is very bad form and completely unnecessary as it could just check (itemSource is ObservableCollection<T>) or better yet (itemSource is INotifyCollectionChanged). I can't find anything about this possibility.